# Check an opening tag of XML in Angular

Tags: angular, xml

I currently have a validation for checking an extension type but I was wondering if there was a way of checking the opening tag of an xml upload file?

This check will allow the upload if true and throw an error (alert) if false.

Comment: Do you mean validate that a document file has a '<xml>' tag **inside** the document? (inside its content)

Comment: It's to check the first line of the xml file, so different files can be validated by the first line. Was thinking regular expression?

Comment: Just as an update for this, I used "required pattern="" in the components .html file for the lh-file-list. This worked